# How do I make gameobject flip and change position when player is facing left?

Tags: unity, c#, 2d

I attached a  a gameobject labeled "Gun" to my player's back and when the player is facing left I want the Gun to continue to look like it's still attached to his back. Right now when I play the game and the player is facing left, the gun stays in the same position it was in regardless of what direction the player is facing. How do I make the gun look like it's still on the players back if facing left? (sorry if it sounds like idk what i'm doing... I'm sorta new to game dev.)

Answer (score 1):

make the weapon child of player and set weapon `order in layer = 1`

then you can do `Scale X` or `Rotate Y` to achieving flip effect.

[image]

```
void Flip(){
    Vector2 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}

/* another method
    void Flip(){
        Vector2 currentRotation = transform.eulerAngles;
        currentRotation.y += 180;
        transform.localEulerAngles = currentRotation;
    }
*/
```

If you want to know player is facing left or right you can do this:

```
 private bool facingRight;

 float h = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
 if(h > 0 && facingRight){
 Flip();
 }else if(h < 0 && !facingRight){
 Flip();
 }

void Flip(){
    facingRight = !facingRight;
    Vector2 scale = transform.localScale;
    scale.x *= -1;
    transform.localScale = scale;
}
```